# Trying to access variables while scraping website; trying to get var in script

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

Trying to web scrape info from this website: http://www.dexel.co.uk/shopping/tyre-results?width=205&profile=55&rim=16&speed=.

For context, I'm trying to find the Tyre brand (Bridgestone, Michelin), pattern (e.g Turanza T001, Ecopia EP500), Tyre Size (205/55. 16 V (91), 225/50. 16 W (100) XL), Seasonality (if available) (Summer, Winter) and price.

My measurements for the tyre are Width – 205, Aspect Ratio – 55, Rim Size - 16.

[image: Tyre website info]

I found all the info I need here at the  var allTyres section. The problem is, I am struggling with how to extract the "manufacturer" (brand), "description" (description has the pattern and size), "winter" (it would have 0 for no and 1 for yes), "summer" (same as winter) and "price".

Afterwards, I want to export the data in CSV format.

Thanks

Comment: this is my first stack overflow question, i apologise if my post isn’t clear enough to understand.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To create a pandas dataframe from the `allTyres` data you can do (from the DataFrame you can select columns you want, save it to CSV etc..):

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "http://www.dexel.co.uk/shopping/tyre-results?width=205&profile=55&rim=16&speed="

data = json.loads(
    re.search(r"allTyres = (.*);", requests.get(url).text).group(1)
)

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
        id ManufacturerID width profile rim speed load                       description          part_no      pattern manufacturer extra_load run_flat winter summer OEList  price tyre_class rolling_resistance wet_grip  Graphic noise_db noise_rating                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 info pattern_name recommended rating
0  1881920            647   205      55  16     V   91              205/55VR16 BUDGET VR      2055516VBUD                   Economy          N        N      0      1         53.20         C1                  G        F      BUD       73            3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0      1
1  3901788            647   205      55  16     H   91              205/55R16 BUDGET 91H      2055516HBUD                   Economy          N        N      0      1         53.20         C1                  G        F      BUD       73            3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0      1
2  1881957            647   205      55  16     W   91              205/55ZR16 BUDGET ZR      2055516ZBUD                   Economy          N        N      0      1         53.54         C1                  G        F      BUD       73            3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0      1
3  6022423            129   205      55  16     H   91  205/55R16 91H UROYAL RAINSPORT 5  2055516HUN09BGS  RainSport 5     Uniroyal          N        N      0      1         70.46         C1                  C        A  UNIRSP5       71            2  <p>The NEW RainSport 5 combines best-in-class wet performance, enhanced mileage, and superior steering control for maximum driving pleasure.</p>\n<ul>\n <li>Safe driving even in the most challenging wet conditions</li>\n <li>Extended tyre life for a long journey</li>\n <li>Excellent control and steering response for maximum driving pleasure.</li>\n</ul>  RainSport 5           0      4
4  6022424            129   205      55  16     V   91  205/55R16 91V UROYAL RAINSPORT 5  2055516VUN09BGR  RainSport 5     Uniroyal          N        N      0      1         70.81         C1                  C        A  UNIRSP5       71            2  <p>The NEW RainSport 5 combines best-in-class wet performance, enhanced mileage, and superior steering control for maximum driving pleasure.</p>\n<ul>\n <li>Safe driving even in the most challenging wet conditions</li>\n <li>Extended tyre life for a long journey</li>\n <li>Excellent control and steering response for maximum driving pleasure.</li>\n</ul>  RainSport 5           0      4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry to ask for more, but how do I pick the certain columns I want (manufacturer, description, etc). I would I include the name of the website being scraped (Dexel)?

Comment: @EzZuk you can do `df = df[["manufacturer", "description"]]` and then `df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)` to save as CSV